# Google Colab having problems with Drive folders containing lots of files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have imported several folders from Drive onto Google Colab. The smaller folders work fine when listing directories, but when I try to list the directories in the larger folders, Colab gives me an error.

I am aware that there are other ways of listing directories, but this same issue is causing problems further down the line when I try to access the files for training.

I am using this to import the files:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

And then describing the folders as follows:

```
TRAIN = '../content/drive/My Drive/train/'
TEST = '../content/drive/My Drive/test/'
```

When I try to do the following:

```
print(os.listdir(TEST))
print(os.listdir(TRAIN))
```

TEST prints fine. It has circa 8000 files (all images).

TRAIN prints some times, others it doesn't! It has circa 32,000 files (all images too).
It prints this when I try to run it:

```
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '../content/drive/My Drive/train/'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in Google colab?

I've found that if after importing the files I wait for a while and then run the prints, it runs, suggesting that Colab takes a while to process the files from Drive even after the cell importing stops running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive FUSE operations can time out when the number of files in a directory becomes large.

I/O operations for Drive directories are proportional to the number of files in the directory. Since there's a fixed timeout in the FUSE client, when the number of files becomes large enough, operations in the directory will fail.

A work-around is to organize your files into subdirectories so that the number of files or folders in a single directory doesn't become so large.

Answer (score 0):

```
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '../content/drive/My Drive/train/'
```

reason is google colab can't read file tree as `'../content/drive/My Drive/train/'`
so, change it as `'content/drive/My Drive/train/'`.(or give full path based on your present working directory)

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it is the relative path that leads to the error. I change it to full path and resolved it.
i.e, change

```
../drive/MyDrive/
```

to

```
/content/drive/MyDrive
```